# How to nicely import CSV contacts to Google Contacts preserving as much information as possible?

Tags: google-sheets, google-contacts, export, import, csv

I was looking at the help file for importing contacts to Google and it didn't specify how to organize the columns:

```
Company First Name  Last Name   Email   Phone   Mobile  Street  City    State   Zip Code    Birthdate   notes
```

These are currently in a Google Sheets `spreadsheet` which originated as `CSV`.  Exporting contacts to `CSV` results in:

```
Name,Given Name,Additional Name,Family Name,Yomi Name,Given Name Yomi,Additional Name Yomi,Family Name Yomi,Name Prefix,Name Suffix,Initials,Nickname,Short Name,Maiden Name,Birthday,Gender,Location,Billing Information,Directory Server,Mileage,Occupation,Hobby,Sensitivity,Priority,Subject,Notes,Language,Photo,Group Membership,E-mail 1 - Type,E-mail 1 - Value,IM 1 - Type,IM 1 - Service,IM 1 - Value,Phone 1 - Type,Phone 1 - Value,Phone 2 - Type,Phone 2 - Value,Phone 3 - Type,Phone 3 - Value,Address 1 - Type,Address 1 - Formatted,Address 1 - Street,Address 1 - City,Address 1 - PO Box,Address 1 - Region,Address 1 - Postal Code,Address 1 - Country,Address 1 - Extended Address,Organization 1 - Type,Organization 1 - Name,Organization 1 - Yomi Name,Organization 1 - Title,Organization 1 - Department,Organization 1 - Symbol,Organization 1 - Location,Organization 1 - Job Description,Website 1 - Type,Website 1 - Value
```

Do the column names have to match exactly for good results?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User three times.

Answer (score 1):

For **best results**, the column names in your CSV should match those found in a [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/) exported CSV.

[Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/) will make a *best effort* when importing data that has alternate column names.

Columns names in a [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/) exported CSV that don't match any data in your own contact fields can be ignored or omited entirely.

In the example below (*My Format*) I omitted any irrelevant column names and used my own versions of column names.  You can see the result of the import below.

#### Example Data

---

###### My Format

| First Name | Last | email | work email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Koala | Bear | test@hlkgjkhfkjgfm.com | testaddf@hlkgjkhfkjgfm.com |

###### Google Contacts Format

| Given Name | Family Name | E-mail 1 - Type | E-mail 1 - Value | E-mail 2 - Type | E-mail 2 - Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Koala | Bear |  | test@hlkgjkhfkjgfm.com | Work | testaddf@hlkgjkhfkjgfm.com |

##### Example Import of My Format

---

[image]